# What's a good prepaid SIM card for data in Ireland?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, ireland

Please recommend an Irish prepaid SIM card for buying a prepaid internet data package.

I'll need about 500MB for a week in Dublin (300-700MB is fine)

Specifically I would purchase a micro SIM for my factory-unlocked iPhone 4, which will server as tether or hotspot for my other devices.

Comment: I'm considering 2.5EUR Tesco Pay-As-You-Go SIM and loading 10EUR airtime which will should buy 500MB at 2c/MB (http://shop.tescomobile.ie/sim-cards.aspx, http://www.tescomobile.ie/other-call-charges.aspx) - open to better ideas, or contradiction if my idea won't work.

Comment: Then there's 3 prepay "Broadband Week" 2GB top-up for 10EUR (http://www.three.ie/products_services/broadband/prepay-broadband.html) - but not sure I could even buy that.

Comment: An 2017 updates / recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Meteor](http://meteor.ie/) offer a 500MB allowance for €4.99 or a 1GB allowance for €9.99. See [here](http://www.meteor.ie/pay-as-you-go/internet-add-ons/) for details.

Comment: Can you buy that once-off as a visitor to Ireland?  It's described as an "internet addon with 30 days free", which sounds like a monthly bill to me.

Comment: It is monthly but you can unsubscribe whenever you want.

Comment: Don't you need an Ireland address to sign up for monthly services?

Comment: No, it is still prepay. You add credit to your account and then the €4.99 is taken from your credit. You don't get a bill.

Comment: The Meteor SIM worked perfectly.  For the €10 I got €10 of airtime AND 1GB of free data (first 30 days).  I did  not have to change any settings on my phone for internet to work.

Comment: I recently bought a prepaid SIM (& cheap phone) in Dublin without any ID requirements or address requirements.

Comment: An 2017 updates / recommendations?